# Dynamically add locale in a Struts2 application

Tags: struts2, locale

I'm working on a project where I need to do a module where administrator can add a locale whenever he want. The project is made with Struts2, Spring and Hibernate.

So, it's can be done by uploading my own locale file within a web application without redeploying it? and how I can rewrite default path to those files? any ideas please? and in general what would be the best idea to do that? Thanks

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by default path? generally we tend to have `localProvider` for this which is responsible for giving us the locale

Comment: I was thinking he means i18n support? Because the local is defined by the client and it really isn't a good idea in general to override that. But being able to provide clients of the application a way to update the i18n setting makes sense.

Comment: Makes, but application reads it on deploy only, so .. I was thinking about another solutiuon maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came to a solution to write locale strings into database itself and rewrite the logic. I think this is the best solution, in that way I am able to modify the strings on the fly even from a page in the admin console.